# How to select and unselect a Powerpoint shape

Tags: asp.net, vba, c#-4.0, powerpoint

I want to know how to select and unselect a Powerpoint shape programatically. I've tried this way to unselect a selected shape, but it doesn't work:

PowerPoint.Shape shape;
.....

shape.Select(Office.MsoTriState.msoFalse);

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not reading the function Select of PowerPoint.Shape. The Select function actually does one of two works:

1) The selection is added to the previous selection.
2) The default. The selection replaces any previous selection.

Answer (score 0):

unselect :
ActiveWindow.Selection.Unselect